# Converting BMP image into greyScale

Tags: c++, image, bmp

I am trying to convert BMP image into greyScale.

I have loaded data ( found and adjusted some functions found here):

```
struct Info{
    int width;
    int height;
    int offset;
    unsigned char * info;
    unsigned char * data;
    int size;
};

    Info readBMP(char* filename)
    {
        int i;
        std::ifstream is(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
        is.seekg(0, is.end);
        i = is.tellg();
        is.seekg(0);
        unsigned char *info = new unsigned char[i];
        is.read((char *)info,i);

        int width = *(int*)&info[17];
        int height = *(int*)&info[21];
        int offset = *(int*)&info[10];

        unsigned char a[offset];
        unsigned char *b = new unsigned char[i - offset];
        std::copy(info,
                  info + offset,
                  a);

        std::copy(info + offset,
                  info + i,
                  b + 0);

        Info dat;
        dat.width = width;
        dat.height = height;
        dat.offset = offset;
        dat.size = i;
        dat.info = new unsigned char[offset - 1];
        dat.data = new unsigned char[i - offset];

        for( int j = 0; j < offset ; j++ ){
            dat.info[j] = a[j];
        }

        for( int j = 0; j < i - offset; j++ ){
            dat.data[j] = b[j];
        }
        return dat;

    }
```

( Loadin works as it should, i tried to load and save data and result was same image )

Now if i understand it correctly, the data should be of `width * height * 3` length.

I am trying to apply greyScale filter using:

```
void greyScale( unsigned char * src , int rows, int cols){
    for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for( int j = 0;  j < cols; j++){
            char r = src[3 * (i * rows + j)];
            char g = src[3 * (i * rows + j) + 1];
            char b = src[3 * (i * rows+ j) + 2];

            char linearIntensity = (char)(0.2126f * r + 0.7512f * g + 0);

            src[3 * (i * rows + j)]= linearIntensity;
            src[3 * (i * rows + j) + 1] = linearIntensity;
            src[3 * (i * rows+ j) + 2] = linearIntensity;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {
    //unsigned char* info = new unsigned char[54];
    Info dat = readBMP("C:\\Users\\Me\\Downloads\\test.bmp");
    greyScale(dat.data,dat.width,dat.height);


    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("out.bmp", ios::binary | ios::out);
    fout.write( reinterpret_cast<char *>(dat.info), dat.offset);
    fout.write( reinterpret_cast<char *>(dat.data), dat.size - dat.offset );
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

However i recieved segfault at j = 3067 and i = 6, which im confused about, cuz it shouldnt be out of index ( the loops shouldnt access anythin out of index ).

I thought it was some padding problem, but padding is just 0 so it shouldnt be problem.

Why is this happening? Why do i recieve good old segfault? I fail to find the reason.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why are you showing us `readBMP`, when there is no relationship whatsoever with the function you say is giving a seg fault?  It seems you could duplicate the entire issue by allocating `src`, and just passing it to the greyscale function, using a dummy `linearIntensity` value and `rows`, `cols` values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie there is still chance of my readBMP being wrong and that can be the issue..

Comment: So we are to piece together two unrelated functions?  Sure, I can duplicate your error, by (mis)allocating `src`, and giving huge `rows` and `cols` values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not sure what you mean, i updated question for usage of 2 methods

Comment: Well your original post had two disjoint functions that had no connection to each other.  Also, why not display those values you found at those magic number indices of 17, 21, and 10?  I don't quite understand why you wouldn't be able to tell if you're going out-of-bounds, given you have all the information required to verify this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh allright i understand, i updated for main function with usage

Comment: What are the dimensions of the input image?

Comment: @WilliamMiller rows = 196096, cols = 130816

Comment: 196096*130816*3 is 76 GB, using an `int` for size you can't read more than 2GB, even if you could I doubt you have enough memory especially as you create 2 copies of the image data

Comment: @rafix07 im actually retarded, didnt notice i put wrong index, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if its a typo, but you seems to be using rows variable instead of cols variable,
try this

```
void greyScale( unsigned char * src , int rows, int cols){
        for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for( int j = 0;  j < cols; j++){
                char r = src[3 * (i * cols + j)];
                char g = src[3 * (i * cols + j) + 1];
                char b = src[3 * (i * cols + j) + 2];

                char linearIntensity = (char)(0.2126f * r + 0.7512f * g + 0);

                src[3 * (i * cols + j)] = linearIntensity;
                src[3 * (i * cols + j) + 1] = linearIntensity;
                src[3 * (i * cols + j) + 2] = linearIntensity;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it wasnt typo, but using cols instead of rows still results in seg fault

Comment: well, if its not a typo then you need to exchange both variables, also as mentioned in comments there is an index error when reading height and width & signed char problem.